# No changes after successful user switch on spring security

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, impersonation, switch-user

I enabled user switch with the following changes to Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSwitchUserFilter = true

grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
 '/j_spring_security_switch_user':['ROLE_SWITCH_USER', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' ],
 '/j_spring_security_exit_user':  ['permitAll']
 ]
```

And on a gsp I have the following:

```
<sec:ifNotSwitched>
    <sec:ifAllGranted roles='ROLE_SWITCH_USER'>
        <form action='${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_switch_user' method='POST'>
            Switch to user: <input type='text' name='j_username' />
            <input type='submit' value='Switch' />
        </form>
    </sec:ifAllGranted>
</sec:ifNotSwitched>
```

When I do the switch I know it works because on my logs I get:

```
Attempt to switch to user [newusername]
switchuser.SwitchUserFilter  - Could not find original user Authentication object!
switchuser.SwitchUserFilter  - Switch User Token [<I see here the username for the user i switched to>]
authentication.AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler  - Using default Url: /
```

And then the app redirects me to the URL i have on springsecurity.switchUser.targetUrl

So far, so good, but then what ever I do on my app still looks like the original/impersonator user, not like the one I switched to

In fact I have another gsp with:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
    Logged in as <sec:username />
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

And nothing is displayed.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm going to assume that `Could not find original user Authentication object!` is the big clue for solving this puzzle.

Comment: Not really, that means that the user trying to do the switch is not already switched to another user. I reviewed the SwithUserFilter class and it basically checks you are not impersonating someone else already before impersonating someone new.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm also using RestTokenValidationFilter and that overrides the authentication after the successful user switch